# ios6 : Crash after launching a video

Tags: ios, xcode, video, modal-dialog, transition

I'm designing a client-server application that sync and stores files on iOS devices.
Launch of video where OK on iOS<6 but with iOS6 the app crashes and the device returns to the springboard

Debugger says :

> 2013-05-17 23:01:03.484 MyApp[526:907] Opening a movie : /var/mobile/Applications/1C5ED030-BBC8-4D56-A979-0BD04DCDEF8A/Documents/MyVideo.mp4
>   2013-05-17 23:01:03.572 MyApp[526:907] *** Assertion failure in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UIWindowController.m:211
>   2013-05-17 23:01:03.574 MyApp[526:907]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to begin a modal transition from  to  while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed'
>   ** First throw call stack:
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

My app uses `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` and `presentModalViewControllerAnimated` methods (deprecated). I tried to replace theses methods by `dismissViewControllerAnimated` and `presentViewControllerAnimated` but the videos are still crashing the app.

Thanks for your help.

PS : VideosViewController.h and .m are here http://github.com/oseres/VideosViewControllerDebug

Comment: where are you presenting the viewController from? You need to wait till viewDidAppear

Comment: do you have strong references to both (ie ivars/properties) that hold them until the transition is complete?

Comment: Thanks @ttarules and david-h 
VideosViewController.h and .m  are here https://github.com/oseres/VideosViewControllerDebug